# How can I go bankrupt in The Factory?

Tags: the-factory

In [The Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electrowolff.factory), it mentions the possibility of going bankrupt. After playing it for two days, I cannot see any way to go bankrupt.

There is a case of buying supplies and re-selling the supplies at the sell price, eventually you will dry out your cash, but really is not the way the game is supposed to be played.

So, discarding what is stated in the above paragraph, how to go bankrupt in a normal (craft and sell products) game-play?